# How can we build multi tenancy on top of hadoop ecosystem?

Tags: hadoop, hive, multi-tenant

We are trying to build multi tenancy on top of hadoop ecosystem.

our ecosystem typically comprise of hadoop components like hdfs, yarn, hive, oozie, zookeeper.

Till now, I have looked onto concepts like

1. [HDFS Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html)

> It federates your distributed storage(HDFS) with the help of a seperate namenode for each federated HDFS partition.
>
> Problem: Say you have 2 tenants for a single cluster hence 2 namenodes, 2 namenodes will imply 2 hive servers, 2 oozie servers and similarly 2 of each of other hadoop components which will communicate with their respective namenode and write in their respective HDFS partition.

2. [Capacity scheduler](http://hortonworks.com/blog/multi-tenancy-in-hdp-2-0-capacity-scheduler-and-yarn/)

> compute quotas could be enforced for each tenant.(say tenant 1 - 50% and tenant 2 - 50%)

3. [MAPR multi tenancy features](https://www.mapr.com/blog/get-real-hadoop-true-multi-tenancy#.VZ9qvl-qqko)

> I could not find how we can develop a similar multi tenant environment for hadoop cluster.

What I was thinking to do was like each tenant(with its users) will have a

1. compute quota(through capacity scheduler)
2. HDFS directory for each tenant in HDFS (like /usr/tenant1, /usr/tenant2)

> All the users belonging to tenant1 group will have access to write in hdfs directory(/usr/tenant1/username)

What problem I faced was..
say i create a table from hive as a tenant1 user, it created the table /apps/hive/warehouse similarly /apps/oozie/data. what I was thinking was it will create table in user's hdfs home directory and hence only tenant1 users will have access to it. but it didn't happen.

Can I get some help in how should I proceed with my development to create multi tenancy over Hadoop ecosystem?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement with multiple namespace in some extent to satisfy your requirements.

I would request you to have a look on Apache blog on Namespace.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html

You can implement multiple namespaces within a namenode.

Kind regards
Andrew